An error occurs when adding column in ObjectListView.repack.Core3 v.2.9.3
An error occurs when adding column in ObjectListView.repack.Core3 v.2.9.3

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type "System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader" to type "BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn".

I can add columns manually by specifying BrihgtIdeasSoftware namespace. But how to do it correctly?

You should provide a minimal example, showing what exactly you are trying to do.

In new project Windows Forms (winForms) (VS 2022), I install the nuget package ObjectListView.repack.Core3 v.2.9.3, drag ObjectListView from toolbox  onto the Form1 , open the column columns collection  and when I try add first column an error occurs.  The second fact that form designer of VS starts to hang.  When I use usual ObjectListView  2.9.1 in WinForms project for .net framework  - all works fine

It seems to be a compatibility issue with the .NET designer. When using .Net Framework, the GUI provides a custom column collection editor which correctly adds an OLVColumn instead of a ColumnHeader. The column should also be added to the AllColumns collection.
Designer code:
        objectListView1 = new ObjectListView();
        columnHeader1 = new ColumnHeader();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)objectListView1).BeginInit();
        SuspendLayout();

        objectListView1.Columns.AddRange(new ColumnHeader[] { columnHeader1 });
        objectListView1.View = View.Details;

        private BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView objectListView1;
        private ColumnHeader columnHeader1;

OLVColumn derives from ColumnHeader. A fixed version would look like this:
        objectListView1 = new ObjectListView();
        columnHeader1 = new OLVColumn(); // fixed
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)objectListView1).BeginInit();
        SuspendLayout();

        objectListView1.AllColumns.Add(this.columnHeader1); // added
        objectListView1.Columns.AddRange(new ColumnHeader[] { columnHeader1 });
        objectListView1.View = View.Details;

        private BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView objectListView1;
        private OLVColumn columnHeader1; // fixed

Using the default column editor afterwards, to make changes to the OLVColumn properties will work.
